# My dog deleted all environment variables PATH's in Win 10, now "npm start" doesn't work

Tags: npm, path, windows-10, environment-variables, npx

Everything was working perfectly fine with "npx create-react-app" and "npm start", until I didn't install Python and my dog delete all env. vars. PATH's in win 10,

and set:

```
C:\Python38-32\Scripts\
C:\Python38-32
C:\Python38-32\airline
```

later I added:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

so now "npx create-react-app" is working, but not and "npm start"

I google to find win 10 defaults and added:

```
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
```

now I have:

```
C:\Python38-32\Scripts\
C:\Python38-32
C:\Python38-32\airline
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
```

How to fix that?

Thank's

Comment: This should be a lesson that you shouldn't do things without understanding exactly what it is you're doing and what the impact will be. Randomly deleting things rarely works out well.

Comment: Hi Ken, I know, right. Shouldn't do things without understanding. 
I see that you are a very experienced back-end dev, can you please check out my other question, thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655458/express-server-back-end-api

Answer (score 0):

So I install fresh windows 10, update windows, installed node.js, and VS code.

THIS IS THE ENV. VAR. PATH'S - NOW EVERYTHING IS WORKING!!!

C:\Python38\Scripts
C:\Python38
%SystemRoot%\system32 %SystemRoot% %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin