# Express server, Back-End, API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, server, backend

### ***Hi, I'm new.***

- started with React.js, by my self, three months ago, on YT.

---

- mostly fetching API

---

- some API's are secured with a signature
- didn't know that my API calls must be on the server, not in React

---

- getting CORS error's
- didn't know what is and how to fix cors.

---

- started to learning a back-end

---

***every video on YT:***

- JSON placeholder
- SWAPI

---

- no video with React and back-end,
- no POST signed request from server video.
- almost give up

---

***CORS error solution:***

- now I know how to fix cors:
- with proxy to express in package.json,
- adding setupProxy.js in src,
- and "app.use(cors())" in Express server.js

---

***My react app:***

- runs 24/7.
- need to update the states every 3s from API.
- then compare states-data. (that is some secret formulas and functions that cannot be exposed to the public if that's even possible. To hide code on the express server.js)
- and take corresponding actions (new API calls).

---

***Question part:***

- is that even possible?
- how the app is working if no one is on the website?
- this means that the Express server.js is always alive
- and React UI is alive only when someone open website to see what's going on with data

---

- how to deploy react-app with express? is this good?:

https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3

---

- how to host - where to deploy? On Github pages?
- do express server autoruns on deploy or do I need "npm start" on hosting
- or open the app for the first time, (open website)
- how that works
- do I need django

---

***what is better:***

- if I decide to share my app with other users:
- to give them each a copy of react app, and they deploy themselves
- or
- make a universal app so each user can log in and have their own express server with dashboard and their own data and states.

---

- if the universal app is better were to learn that

---

---

### Thank you for any question that is answered.

---

Comment: can you edit your question to make it more readable? I appreciate the effort, simple will do.

Comment: get a book/class/training/course or tutoring. The yt videos don't show all of this because they would be too long. The same goes with stackoverflow questions.

Comment: marcelin - can you point me to some genuine resources.
or help me with setting up environment variables PATH's in Win 10 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653980/i-deleted-all-environment-variables-paths-in-win-10-now-npm-start-doesnt-wo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server runs 24/7

when a user wants to access a page of the website, the server sends it the page's blueprint (the html, css and js, which in this case is built by your react js build code), that's when your react app comes alive.

you already have express for server side, you don't need django.

yea deploying with heroku is fine. it'll take care of the server but you'll have to add a script in the server's package.json to make it build react, if you're not already uploading a react build to heroku.

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

here client is the folder you keep your react code in.

If it's not supposed to be public, you shouldn't have it as a react state.

Using a universal thing is better, just make an account system with owner as a privilege, and have the url in the form of [www.website.com/owner'susername](http://www.website.com/owner%27susername)
and done, every owner gets their own version of the website.

(there's an awesome MERN stack tutorial on youtube by traversy media that answers most of your questions)